# jQuery how to break .load() on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know when is ajax, making `var a=$.ajax`...and i can abort that...but what i have to do when is `$(".cont").load("somepage.php",function(){});` how i can stop proces when click on some button?
one explain:

```
$(".cont").delegate(".a","click",function(){
    var cont=$(this).text();
    //stop ajax i mean load() than load new on click to div with other contains
    $(".load:contains('"+cont+"')").load('somepage.php',function(){
       //some function
    });
});
```

I getting problem if i fast change click to other one, ajax load wrong page.

Answer (score 1):

`load`, the way you're using it, is basically just `ajax` and then `html`, so you could just do the two parts (since you know how to abort an `ajax` request):

```
$(".cont").delegate(".a","click",function(){
    var cont=$(this).text();
    var a = $.ajax({
        url: "somepage.php",
        success: function(html) {
            $(".load:contains('"+cont+"')").html(html);
        }
    });
});
```